# list of entries below the page. its like adding 2 textboxes controls into formarray

Tags: angular, formarray

Hi  i need angular 4 code for the requirement like there will 2 textboxes and add button once clicking on add button it should push 2 textboxes data into list of entries below the page. its like adding 2 textboxes controls into formarray.

Comment: please post what have you done so far

Answer (score 0):

In your typescript:

```
public formArray:any=[];
ngOnInit(){
   this.formArray = [{textbox1: null, textbox2: null}];
}

addButtonClick(){
    this.formArray.push({textbox1: null, textbox2: null});
}
```

In your html page:

```
<button (click)="addButtonClick()" > Add<button><br />
<div *ngFor="let obj of formArray">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.textbox1" />
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.textbox2" />
</div>
```

This is the logic,
Hope this will help you!!